# National MessageBox title translation

Tags: winapi

I'm using the WinAPI MessageBox to show information to the users.

It uses the local translations for the buttons. Is there any way to get the local translations for "Information", "Error", "Confirmation" and "Question"?

Maybe any DLL, where I can get the resource string from... ?

Inside the user32.dll, I found "Yes", "No", "Ok", "Cancel" and more - but nothing for "Information", "Error", "Confirmation" and "Question".

Comment: The language of the text of Win32 dialogs is controlled by the Windows language selection, and users must first install the appropriate Windows Language Pack too. You cannot control this from code, or override this in your code.

Comment: Save yourself all this trouble by using the system provided dialogs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I thought `MessageBox` would be a system provided dialog. What happened with you? A long time, you gave very good answers to me. But in the last weeks, you sounds very frustrated and ignorant. Maybe you should make some holidays to relax...

Comment: It is a system provided dialog. You use it and the dialog appears in the local language. You don't need to know the text on the buttons.

Comment: I didn't ask about the button texts - I asked about the caption. Seems I'm right, and you are very ignorant in the moment. Please relax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User32 does contain the string for "Error" (resource id 2 on my machine), it is used when the title parameter is NULL.

Even if it did contain the other strings it would not be a good idea to use them because the resource identifiers are not documented and could change in the future.

Because you need to provide the translation for the main text you might as well just provide your own translations for the title as well...